# How to realize direct arrows with PlantUML?

Tags: uml, plantuml

I am trying to create an activity diagram with PlantUML that does contain arrows that go back to existing nodes.

What I am looking for is a diagram that includes the two arrows "Arrow 1" and "Arrow 2" in the picture below:
[image: plantuml diagram with the desired arrows]

I have tried creating this using the [PlantUML beta syntax for Activity diagrams](https://plantuml.com/de/activity-diagram-beta).

I achieved the diagram below:

[image: plantuml diagram without the desired arrows]

by writing the following PlantUML code:

```
@startuml

start

:new - please check;

while (check sucessful?) is (is an error)
  :to solve;
  :in progress;
  :solved;
endwhile (not an error)

:erledigt;
note left
    reason:
     * done
     * not an error
     * not fixable
end note
stop

@enduml
```

Does anybody has a hint on how to achieve this? It does not matter to me if the result is achieved by using the beta syntax or [the older syntax](https://plantuml.com/de/activity-diagram-legacy).

Comment: I have no idea about plantuml but on your additional arrows there should be guards. Maybe that's what plantuml expects?

Comment: And as a side note: your two "guards" must be written in square brackets in order to be syntactically correct.

Comment: @qwerty_so: In the final diagram there should be guards, that's true. (Otherwise there would be no chance of knowing when to take  which path).
But I don't think this is the missing part to making it work in plantUML as guards are optional there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot have several flows starting from an action nor several flows going to an action

for the UML point of view so you need to add :

1. a decision node after the action "to solve" to have your two flows, each with a guard
2. a decision node after the action "erledigt" to have your two flows, each with a guard
3. a merge node before the action "to solve" to receive the flows from the decision node "check successful" and the action "erledigt".

For (1) use a "if-else" or a "split" in PlantUML

> ```
> start
>
> :new - please check;
>
> while (check sucessful?) is (is an error)
>   :to solve;
>   if (duration) then (long)
>     :in progress;
>   else (immediat)
>   endif
>   :solved;
> endwhile (not an error)
>
> :erledigt;
> note left
>     reason:
>      * done
>      * not an error
>      * not fixable
> end note
> stop
>
> @enduml
> ```

[image]

For (3) may be you can use a "repeat while" also managing (2), but not sure you can in PlantUML without duplicating the three actions (to solve - in progress - solved) or doing them in an other activity you call. In PlantUML the code is drawn from control-structure except "goto", that allows to not cross lines, but you need a "goto" crossing lines. Note there is no problem going to the decision "check sucessfull" rather than to the action "to solve"

Comment: Thanks @bruno, this works for me :-)

It also put me on the right track for what I really needed. I am much better of modeling my case as a state chart than an activity diagram. (Would give you two upvotes if I could ;-) )

Comment: *you cannot have* should probably end with "for PlantUML" since UML can have it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are using the wrong diagram here: If you are using a StateDiagram instead of an ActivityDiagram you can add multiple connections between the nodes. That's at least what I think you want to express with the initial diagram.

The necessary activities are usually placed at the arrows then.